# Progress bars in Java

Tags: java, swing, class, methods

I have a code with two methods.

```
public void fondo() { ... }        //Gathers JFrame Background and system time
public void recuperarDatosInternet() {...} //Connects to a URL and gets data.
```

When the JFrame is running, at the beginning it takes four or five seconds to perform all the operations of those methods.

While it's loading, the frame displays totally empty for 3 or 4 seconds until all the methods are complete, then the frame shows up and it's all right.

How can I make a Progress Bar that shows the user that something it's loading?
I don't mean a ProgressBar that are predetermined to take "4000 ms". I am referring to a progressbar that can take whatever it takes, and the bar doesn't reach the 100% until the methods are complete.

Comment: Check the topic in the Java tutorials: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html I recommend you use an "indeterminate mode" progress bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run heavy task in [The Event Dispatch Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) it's gonna to freeze until finish to avoid that you can execute the download in another thread using `SwingWorker`. 
Follow this [link](http://www.javacreed.com/swing-worker-example/) to see a complete example with `progressBar` , special attention to [setProgress()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#setProgress%28int%29) [publish()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish%28V...%29) and [process()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#process%28java.util.List%29).

Example:

```
public class MyWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, String> {

  @Override
  protected Integer doInBackground() throws Exception {
    // Start
    publish("Start Download");
    setProgress(1);

    // More work was done
    publish("More work was done");
    setProgress(10);

    // Complete
    publish("Complete");
    setProgress(100);
    return 1;
  }

  @Override
  protected void process(List< String> chunks) {
    // Messages received from the doInBackground() (when invoking the publish() method)
  }
}
```

and in client code:

```
    SwingWorker worker = new MyWorker();
    worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new MyProgressListener());
    worker.execute();

   class MyProgressListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
      @Override
      public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent event) {
        if(event.getPropertyName().equalsIgnoreCase("progress")) {
          downloadProgressBar.setIndeterminate(false);
          downloadProgressBar.setValue((Integer) event.getNewValue());
        }         
      }
     }
```

Comment: OK. I read this before, and I didn't manage to put the code on my program. Not because it's wrong, but because I don't know how to do this using the netbeans "swing" editor. That code explains how to do it by invoking all the swing components (I mean, "writing" them). I had already done that! Using the design view. So when I try to invoke a swing component, it always throw a mistake I'm not able to solve

Comment: @SebaPaz Mm i don't think you have to do it with the netbeans swing editor (also called matisse) cause you are doing anything with gui components. you have to code without the editor..

Comment: I'm not accostumed to, but I will try that. Anyway, ¿is there a possible way to do this faster using matisse?

Comment: @SebaPaz Mmm i don't think so, cause swingWorker it's not a swing gui component.. i would try to not "marry" with matisse, and start coding! If you have problems after  you try something you can post a new question here in stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for this. This class enables allows the time-consuming work to be done in background thread and does not hold up the user-interface in the meantime. It also has the facility to divide the work up into 'chunks' and to update the user-interface on the completion of these chunks of work. This is what you would need for a progress bar, although it depends on your task being 'chunkable'. The link above takes you to the JavaDoc for this class which contains an example for both the simple and the 'chunked' usage.